# IOS Archiving App face problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, archive

Today I want to make my app into TestFlight that test my app. Before I do this, i use my app in simulator and my iPhone. The program is running normal. when I achieve the some iTunes Connection configure, I archiving this app. Some times later, I accept some mistakes:

1. `SVProgressHUD.h` file not found
2. failed to import bridging header `/Users/showxjn/Documents/YikaTomApp/LoveFreshBeen-master-2/LoveFreshBeen/LoveFreshBeen-Bridging-Header.h`

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Did you change the name of your app recently ? Or the name of your target ?

Comment: oh, my project name is LoveFreshBeen, later I change the name to yikatomhandyshop

Comment: How can I solve this problem

Comment: Can you include the contents of your podfile in the question? I think you might have to run a pod install again which might solve the missing 'SVProgressHUD.h file not found' error

Comment: Long shot, try connecting through an ethernet connection and turn wifi off.

Comment: the problem is my simulator and iPhone all running this program

Answer (score 0):

my pod file is :
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod "SVProgressHUD"

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'LoveFreshBeen' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end